# Car simulation, motor torque and brake torque combine problem

Tags: unity, physics, car

I am creating a custom wheel collider in Unity. Every thing is fine now (suspension, collision, friction) except one problem that i cant get my head over for last 3 weeks. So now i have a car (one wheel only), it stand on top of a hill, then i apply a brake torque enough to make it stand still, after that i apply a motor torque that less than max brake torque, my question is how the car behave?. In my opinion, that if sum of motor torque (roll down hill direction) and gravity torque(friction force * radius) greater than the max brake torque will cause the car to roll down hill, and it remain stand still if motor torque (roll up hill direction). I really need help!

So i have mT(motor torque), bT(max brake torque), fT(max ground torque), rT(residual torque)

```
if (|mT| > |bT|) {

    |rT| = |mT| - |bT|; 

    if (|rT| > |fT|) {
        wheel spin up with sign(mT) * (|rT| - |fT|);
        ground force = sign(mT) * |fT| / radius;
    } else {
        wheel roll without slipping;
        ground force = mT / radius;
    }
} else { 

    |rT| = |bT| - |mT|; 

    if (|rT| > |fT|) {
         wheel slow down to 0 with -sign(omega) * (|rT| - |fT|); 
         ground force = -sign(velocity) * |fT| / radius;
     } else {
         wheel roll without slipping;
         ground force = -sign(velocity) * (|bT| - sign(velocity) * mT) / radius;
     } 
}
```

All torque sign are on top.

Comment: As i stated before, i just want to know the right concept of the problem, like: it will happen like my opinion or |bT| will cancel out |mT| and leave |rT| = |bT| - |mT| to brake..., that is the thing i cant help my head over for along time. If i got the right concept i can continue to implement without a doubt.

Comment: Implement your concept first, then see if it works for your game. If it does not, then post a description of the problem it causes and we can help you solve that problem. If it does work for your game, then you're off to the races, and you never had to spend time asking the question at all.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i don't know if my question is not clear or something but again i just want to know the physics concept in this situation, forget about implementation or those code.

Comment: Forget about the physics concept. Your answer is already good enough to try. Don't worry about what's "correct" — games are approximations, almost nothing we do is "exactly accurate", and it would often feel terrible to play if it were! Reality often has awful game feel. Or, taken from another angle, games are virtual worlds of your own creation: anything you choose can be "correct" for the universe you've made. So, err on the side of boldness: just try what you have, and test whether it causes a problem.